# How to access context variable within the template component in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Within a react component in a Gatsby app, I understand how to use a context variable within the graphql queries, e.g:

```
export const tagPageQuery = graphql`
  query TagPage($tag: String) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allItem(filter: { tags: { in: [$tag] } }) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {

          id
          move
          videoUrl
```

`$tag` is a string that allows me to filter. I get that. But is there someway to access this value within the component itself? I can access the data that the graphql query gets, but can't get the variable outside of Graphql. I would love to have it be `{context.tag}` or something like that, to be able to use that value within my `h1`. I've gone through the [Gatsby GraphQL reference](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/graphql-reference/) and no dice. It feels like getting this value should be easy but I'm wondering if I need to use something like a `getContext` hook?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Amazing what a 10 minute mini nap can do! Indeed, you can access context variables with the pageContext prop detailed here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs

```
const TagPage = ({ data, classes , pageContext}) => {
```

Adding pageContext to my props allowed me to get access to `$tag`.